# Why doesn't "trusted user" apply to tag synonyms? Is this a bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, feature-request, tags

I'm curious of anybody knows the rationale for excluding the tag synonym suggestion feature from the set of features trusted users are allowed to perform?

It seems particularly odd to me that, as a trusted user, I am able to edit tag wikis with impunity, but I'm not allowed to set up or even suggest synonyms. I have to go through the same scores gates as everybody else (having a score of five or more in the tag).

I don't think one needs to be an "expert" in the tag in know that, for example, the `d3d` and `direct3d` tags are synonyms. The fact that only diamond moderators can perform some of these tags operations means they are more of a bottleneck and it's harder for the community to facilitate the cleanup of less-popular tags in the system.

If this isn't a bug, I'd really like to see it implemented or at least get an explanation as to why it's such a restricted feature.

(Perhaps this is a better question for the SO meta in general? It sort of seems like they'd prefer you to ask on the site-specific meta first, but I'm unclear.)

Comment: Personally, I think that suggesting a tag synonym ain't such a big deal. It's also pretty hidden away, in order to spawn a lot of false-positives. Well, maybe a moderator should accept the synonym as valid to be voted for. Something like flag system.

Comment: Sometimes there are super obvious tag synonyms (that should be there, but apparently are not at the moment), so creating a meta post about it in order to create it, especially for users with tons of rep, doesn't seem logical.

Comment: Also, you should post this on SO meta, since this applies to all sites.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag